# Google Chrome console run a command in every page of a particular website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, console

I am visiting a website which I think has a bug. And I have tried running a javascript function (defined by them), after running the function the site works smoothly in that page. After I navigate to a different page, I again have to run the function. So I want it to run automatically after the page loads. I am using google chrome. So, are there any chrome extensions or any built in thing that can do this. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think tampermonkey is what you are looking for 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to write an extension that [injects code in the page's context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).

It's important, because normally code in the extension is isolated from the page.

Tampermonkey route is probably better though in your case.